# Closest positive definite matrix to arbitrary one

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a real symmetric nondegenerate matrix with complex eigenvalues. How can one find the closest (in terms of $L^2$ or $L^p$ norm) positive definite matrix?

Conversely, given a non-definite quadratic form $x^TMx$ where $x$ lies in the unit circle, what would be the closest positive definite quadratic form to approximate the given one for such $x$'s?

Comment: real symmetric matrix will have real eigenvalues.

Comment: The set of all positive definite matrices is not closed. So, in general, unless your matrix is PD right from the start, no solution exists. Maybe you are looking for the closest positive semidefinite matrix?

Comment: For the $2$-norm: find the orthogonal eigendecomposition of the matrix and replace all negative eigenvalues with $0$.

Comment: Also: that's not what "conversely" means.